# Qt не видит классы QPrinter и QPrintDialog

Tags: qt

Изучаю Qt Creator, работаю с виджетами. При сборке приложения компилятор ругается на классы QPrinter и QPrintDialog. Пишет, что не определена ссылка. Хотя включены соответствующие заголовочные файлы. Подскажите в чём может быть причина. Почему Qt Creator распознаёт классы, но при создании объектов этих классов выдаёт такие ошибки?[image: Привёл скриншот с ошибками]

Answer (score 2):

У вас модуль не подключен. Добавьте `QT += printsupport` в .pro

https://doc.qt.io/QT-5/qprinter.html

Comment: Подключил модуль QT += printsupport в .pro файл, очистил проект, пересобрал, ошибки остались... Может быть ещё какие-то возможные причины есть?

Comment: Попробуйте вручную запустить qmake, может помочь. Хотя он должен был автоматом запуститься при изменении .pro

Answer (score 1):

Как выше уже сказали
добавить QT += printsupport в .pro
и перепишите инклюды по человечески. После подключения printsupport:

```
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPrintDialog>
```